# Integration problem : difference between two draws from an hyperbolic secant probability distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration

I would like to find the distribution of the difference between two independent draws from a random variable which follows a secant hyperbolic distribution whose density function is :
$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\operatorname{sech}(\frac{\pi}{2}x)$

where $\operatorname{sech}(x)=\cosh(x)^{-1}$

$\operatorname{sech}$ can be integrated (cf Wikipedia) :
$\int \operatorname{sech}(ax) = a^{-1} \arctan(\sinh(ax)) +C$

To get my distribution, I need to integrate :
$$g(x)=\int \operatorname{sech}(t-\frac{x}{2})\operatorname{sech}(t+\frac{x}{2})dt$$

$$g(x)=\int \frac{4}{e^{2t}+e^{-2t}+e^x+e^{-x}}dt$$

So, to put it simplier, I need to integrate :

$$h(x)=\frac{1}{e^x+e^{-x}+C}$$

I don't know how to go further.

We can notice that, when C=0, it is the same problem as integrating $\operatorname{sech}$ (Unfortunaltely, I have only the result, not the demonstration that could probably be helpful)

Comment: You can get displayed equations by using double instead of single dollar signs. (This is particularly relevant when you're mixing integrals, fractions and exponents, to keep the equations easy to read.)

Comment: You can get the proper font and spacing for $\cosh$ using `\cosh`. For operators like $\operatorname{sech}$ that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{sech}`.

Comment: Thank you. I have made the proposed changes.

Comment: Do you not need $g(x)=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\text{sech}\left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right) \text{sech}\left(\frac{1}{2} \pi  \{t+x\}\right)}{4} \, dx=\frac{1}{2} t \text{csch}\left(\frac{\pi  t}{2}\right)$ if $t \neq 0$ and $g(0)=\frac{1}{\pi }$ ?

Comment: @JimB This is definitely what I need! Maybe you should add it as an answer. Furhtermore, how did you get that result ?

Answer (score 1):

Using *Mathematica* one can obtain $g(x)$:

```
f[x_] := 1/2 Sech[(x π)/2]
g[z_] := Evaluate[Integrate[f[x1] f[x1 + z], {x1, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> z ∈ Reals]]
g[z]
(* 1/2 z Csch[(π z)/2] *)
```

As a partial check take a random sample for $x_1$ and $x_2$, take the difference, and compare the resulting histogram to the probability density function:

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[(1/2) Sech[(x π)/2], {x, -∞, ∞}];
x1 = RandomVariate[dist, 1000000];
x2 = RandomVariate[dist, 1000000];
zz = x1 - x2;
Show[Histogram[zz, Automatic, "PDF"],
  Plot[g[z], {z, -5, 5}]]
```

[image: Histogram and PDF]

** Steps to obtain the integral **

Using the [Rubi](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) package in *Mathematica* the first steps in solving the integral are as follows:

```
Steps[Int[f[x1] f[x1 + z], x1]]
```

[image: Steps taken by Rubi]

This results in

```
-((Csch[(π z)/2] Log[Cosh[(π x1)/2]])/(2 π)) + (Csch[(π z)/2] Log[Cosh[(π x1)/2 + (π z)/2]])/(2 π)
```

for the anti-derivative.  The difference in the anti-derivative for $x_1=\infty$ and $x_1=-\infty$ is

```
-((Csch[(π z)/2] Log[E^(-((π z)/2))])/(2 π)) + (Csch[(π z)/2] Log[E^((π z)/2)])/(2 π)
```

This is simplified in *Mathematica* with

```
-((Csch[(π z)/2] Log[E^(-((π z)/2))])/(2 π)) + (Csch[(π z)/2] Log[E^((π z)/2)])/(2 π) /. Log[Exp[x_]] -> x
```

resulting in the answer:

```
1/2 z Csch[(π z)/2]
```

Comment: It is very helpful. But I can not consider it as the answer because there it is not a  mathematical proof.

Comment: Understood.  The best I can do is supply the steps given by the Rubi package used in *Mathematica*.